# Custom event page not keep event ID when click on Review button

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I have a page called event and set the bellow rewrite rule to store the event ID in the URL:

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^event/(\d+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=event&event_id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
});

add_filter('query_vars', function ($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'event_id';
    return $vars;
});
```

e.g. mysite.com/event/37/

Works fine until user clicks on Review button and CiviCRM removes the id from URL:

e.g. mysite.com/event/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&_qf_Register_display=true&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistration...

Is there a way to keep the ID or get the event ID using other solution?

Comment: Depends upon how you using it. Are you using Civi hooks or wp hooks?

Comment: @PradeepNayak You mean to render the event form? I'm using shortcode and set the Shortcode Display Mode to "Remain in Shortcode Mode".

Comment: any reason you want to retain the id? What you trying to achieve by adding id in the URL?

Comment: @PradeepNayak the layout of the event page is very customized. I need the event ID to get things like the event title.

Comment: Have you tried civicrm hooks to alter the pages? like buildForm or preProcess

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using CiviCRM [buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) or [preProcess](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_preProcess/) hook to alter the event registration pages

Comment: I'm using `civicrm_buildForm` to add a hidden field with the event id and I'm able to get this value using `$_POST` when user click on Review button. However, I'm not able to do the same when user click on Go Back button.

Comment: you can use $form->getVar('_id'); to get the event id, if you want to store that id somewhere so that you can access it in any function you can use Civi::$statics['myCustomPluginName']['eventId'] = $form->getVar('_id');

Comment: I'm using `civicrm_buildForm` to store the event form ID, but it seems like the trigger fires too late and I can't use it inside a WordPress template.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this issue was to use the filter `page_link`, called (indirectly) by `get_permalink` function. This way, the URL used on form `action` attribute is correct.